# Why do we need to escape the ! < > : = - in php regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, web

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php:

> The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) {
>   } = ! < > | : -

However [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) says that special characters are `[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( )`

Ok I know that the first page is specifically on php regular expressions. However why do we need to escape  the `!`, `<`, `>`, `:`, `=`, `-` ?

I tried to do a `preg_match` without escaping `<`, `>`, `-` and `!` and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those characters are metacharacters, but they need no escaping. What they do have in common is that they occur in special grouping constructs:

```
(?:...)      # non-capturing group
(?=...)      # positive lookahead
(?!...)      # negative lookahead
(?<name>...) # named capturing groups
(?<=...)     # positive lookbehind
(?<!...)     # negative lookbehind
(?>...)      # atomic group
```

But they only take on a special meaning in this context. So if you take any string and escape all these characters: `[\^$.|?*+(){`, then you get a regex that will exactly match the string character by character because those other metacharacters can never be in a meta-context.

For example, the `]` is only a metacharacter if there was a previous unescaped `[` that opened a character class.

Similarly, the `-` is only a metacharacter in a character class, meaning "range" as in `[a-z]` <sub>(or a literal `-` as in `[abc-]`</sub>.

So to escape the string `[tag-soup]` you just need to escape the `[`. Outside of a character class, `]` and `-` are simply treated as literals.

In summary, if you take a string and escape all the "unconditional" metacharacters (`[\^$.|?*+(){`) then you get a regex that will exactly match the string character by character.

Comment: why does `preg_quote` escapes them if they need no escaping ? what's the catch ?

Comment: Sounds a bit overzealous to me. If your input string is `(?:)`, then `\(\?:\)` would be the correctly escaped version. `\(\?\:\)` probably won't hurt since in many regex flavors unknown escape sequences are simply ignored, but some do trigger errors on them, so it's usually a good idea not to escape more than needed.

Comment: is there even 1 situation where not escaping those may fail anything ? or is it safe to assume it won't fail 100%.

Comment: No, it's safe. I have added `{` to the list of "to be escaped" characters, that had been missing, but that's it then.

Answer (score 4):

The page you link to is titled "basic regex syntax". There is a link to a page titled ["advanced regex syntax"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).  Here all the extra characters you specify are used.

- `!` is used for negative lookaheads and lookbehinds
- `<` is used for lookbehinds
- `>` is used for atomic groups
- `:` is used for setting flags for only a section of a regex
- `=` is used for positive lookaheads and lookbehinds
- `-` is used for character ranges and adjusting flags

Comment: but why do we need to escape them ? why does `preg_quote` escapes them? Even though i didn't escape them, everything is working fine.

Comment: @Pacerier Because you might be inserting only part of a regex. The circumstances where it would be a problem are pretty obscure, but not inconceivable.

Comment: could you give 1 example (possibly in question edit thx) how not escaping a ! or < or > is going to fail ? because yes it is inconceivable for me right now.

Answer (score 3):

A dash is a special character inside character classes:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

The others have significance inside match groups, for example for lookahead/lookbehind:

```
(?<=foo)
(?!bar)
```

I agree with you that none of these need to be escaped. Once the parentheses and square brackets are escaped these other characters lose their special meaning.

Comment: why does `preg_quote` escapes them if they need no escaping ? what's the catch ?

Comment: There is no catch.  Those characters do not need to be escaped.  Whoever wrote that method was just being over-enthusiastic.

Answer (score 1):

These characters are used in negative/positive look-behind/ahead/around expressions.  For example:

```
/^foo(?<!z)bar$/
```

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Many characters are special only in a certain context. From the basic ones, a few examples:

```
 /-/       # dash
 /[a-z]/   # range
 /[-a-z]/  # a-z or dash

 /[^]/     # literal
 /^/       # meta-character

 /!/       # literal
 /(?!...)/ # meta-character
```